# Import cannot resolve java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

The error pop up is "import cannot be resolve" only on  import "org.apache.log4j.Logger;" .... this is the Main.java
and the other java class is have the same error... any one can fix or help?
this is sending sms

```
package com.dbs.epodsms;

import com.dbs.epodsms.business.logic.ConfigureModem;
import com.dbs.epodsms.business.logic.SmsProcessor;
import com.dbs.epodsms.business.object.Log;
import com.dbs.epodsms.business.object.Outgoing;
import com.dbs.epodsms.misc.Network;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main
{
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    logger.info("Application started.");
    List<Outgoing> outgoingList = new ArrayList<Outgoing>();
    SmsProcessor smsProcessor = new SmsProcessor();

    try
    {
      ConfigureModem cfgModem = ConfigureModem.getInstance();

      if (!cfgModem.configure())
      {
        logger.error(cfgModem.getMessage());
        logger.error("An error occured while configuring your modem. Please check that your modem is properly installed and that the hw is not defective.");
        logger.info("The application will now exit.");
        System.exit(0);
      }


      List<Outgoing> oldOutgoingList = smsProcessor.getOutgoingList(Network.GLOBE);

      if (oldOutgoingList.size() > 0)
      {
        outgoingList.addAll(oldOutgoingList);
      }

      outgoingList.addAll(smsProcessor.getNewSMS(cfgModem.getGateway()));
      logger.info("Processing a total of " + outgoingList.size() + " sms...");

      for (Outgoing o : outgoingList)
      {
        if (o.getRetries() > 3)
        {
          smsProcessor.sendEmail(o);
        }
        else if (smsProcessor.sendSMS(o))
        {
          logger.info("SMS was sent successfully.");
          Log log = new Log();
          log.setRemarks("REPLY SENT");
          log.setSenderNumber(o.getRecipient());
          log.setSms(o.getMessage());
          smsProcessor.saveToLog(log);
          smsProcessor.deleteOutging(o.getId());
        }
        else
        {
          logger.error("Error sending message to " + o.getRecipient());
          o.setRetries(o.getRetries() + 1);
          smsProcessor.addOrUpdateOutgoing(o);
        }
      }

      logger.info("Stopping service...");
      cfgModem.stopService();
      smsProcessor.closeDBConnection();
      System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      logger.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the log4j Jar file in your classpath. In your Java project, right click and select "Build Path -> Configure Build Path", and in the libraries tab add the Jar file.